# How to start/stop service from python script running in Flask and Apache server using Debian?

Tags: python, apache, service, flask, debian

I'm trying to start and stop services from a python script that is running using Flask and Apache.

To get the status from memcached, for example, I'm using

`os.popen('service memcached status').read()` and works like a charm.

The problem is that when I try to start/stop doing something like

`os.popen('service memcached stop').read()` it just does nothing (I checked by the shell that the service is still running)

To summarize, I can get the status but can't start/stop and don't know why its happens.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: try using subprocess instead of os. I believe os.popen is deprecated

Comment: maybe you need root/admin privileges so you need `sudo` (or `su`) but it will ask for password.

Comment: @furas Thank you! You give me the way to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the apache logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and the problem was that I needed more privileges to execute start/stop. But when I tried to use

```
os.popen('sudo service memcached stop').read()
```

I got an error, saying that I should have typed the su password.

To solve this problem I typed in the shell:

```
visudo
```

which opened the `/etc/sudoers` file. And there I added the line

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I understood that this means that I am giving permission to the user `www-data` execute `sudo` without password.

To quit, press `Ctrl+X` and then `y` to save.

note: `www-data` is the username that executes the apache.